# How to show 3 Cards in a Row in Bootstrap Grid System

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add 3 cards in a row using bootstrap grid system but the problem is that when I use Django loop each card is showing on its own in each row which is not what I want. I have searched for the answer and I have added it to show my trial but it did not work.

Here is the template.html before adding django loop

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img
        src=""
        class="card-img-top"
        alt="..."
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
          additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img
        src=""
        class="card-img-top"
        alt="..."
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
          content.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img
        src=""
        class="card-img-top"
        alt="..."
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
          additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show
          that equal height action.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is after the django looping

```
{% for item in object_list %}

<div class="card-group">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <embed
        src="{{ item.image.url }}"
        class="card-img-top"
        alt="..."
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.title }}</h5>
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold blue-text">
                <strong>
                    {% if item.discount_price %}
                    <small><span class="badge badge-pill danger-color">Discount was <del>${{ item.price }}</del></span></small>
                    <br>
                    Now ${{ item.discount_price }}
                    {% else %}
                    ${{ item.price}}
                    {% endif %}
                </strong>
            </h4>
        <p class="card-text">
        {{ item.description }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I set to have 3 cards in a row and get fixed at this size? There is no CSS file it is bootstrap only and it is working fine without django but when i remove a card it gets enlarged fitting whatever cards available to the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get three cards in a row you need to specify the column width per row. From [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

> Thanks to flexbox, grid columns without a specified width will automatically layout as equal width columns. For example, four instances of .col-sm will each automatically be 25% wide from the small breakpoint and up. See the auto-layout columns section for more examples.
> Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. So, if you want three equal-width columns across, you can use .col-4.

So in your case you would have

```
<div class='row card-group'>
{% for item in object_list %}
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <embed
        src="{{ item.image.url }}"
        class="card-img-top"
        alt="..."
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.title }}</h5>
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold blue-text">
                <strong>
                    {% if item.discount_price %}
                    <small><span class="badge badge-pill danger-color">Discount was <del>${{ item.price }}</del></span></small>
                    <br>
                    Now ${{ item.discount_price }}
                    {% else %}
                    ${{ item.price}}
                    {% endif %}
                </strong>
            </h4>
        <p class="card-text">
        {{ item.description }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```